# Can't get symfony to follow symbolic links to my resources

Tags: php, symfony1, symlink

i have the resources shared with another project. The pictures of the products i will show, are stored in a folder out of my new project for which im using symfony...

In my symfony project, in the `/web/images` folder, i created a symbolic link to the folder where my pictures are stored. im sure the permissions of every file and folder under the pictures folder pointed by the symlink are setted 777, anyone can access to them.

Everything worked fine until i enabled the mod rewrite of apache. Pictures on the `/web/images` folder were shown perfectly, buy anything accessible through the symlink wasn't shown.  I immediately thought the symlink was the reason of this behavior, and i checked my apache configuration for the site. Also, reading on symfony, i examined the `.htaccess` file under the `/web` folder and added the line:

`Options FollowSymLinks`

This didn't work either.

Here's my site configuration:

```
#<VirtualHost mydomain.com>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    #DocumentRoot /var/www
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/mydomain.com/public_html/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        #AllowOverride None
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    #<Directory /var/www/>
    <Directory /srv/www/mydomain.com/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        #AllowOverride None
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        #AllowOverride None
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        #Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    ErrorLog /srv/www/mydomain.com/logs/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    CustomLog /srv/www/mydomain.com/logs/access.log combined

    Alias /sf /home/victor/projects/vitoquen/tienda/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
    <Directory "/home/victor/projects/vitoquen/tienda/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    #Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    #<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    #    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    #    #AllowOverride None
    #    AllowOverride All
    #    Order deny,allow
    #    Deny from all
    #    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    #</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And here's my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  Options FollowSymLinks

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions?? thanks for taking the time of reading and answering!!!

**EDIT:**

I tried the [Znarkus'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138023/znarkus) solution, and didnt work! this, i think, can mean that the symlink was not the problem.

Files in the pictures folder are stored without extention. Because of than, i cant use the `image_tag()` helper of symfony, which appends `.png` by default to the file name if no extention is given... this is the way im displaying images in my template:

```
if (strcmp($producto->foto, "SI") == 0) {
    echo '<img src="/images/productos/'.$producto->id.'_muestra" width="102" height="84"  alt="Imagen de muestra"/>';
} else {
    echo '<img src="/images/no_picture.jpg" width="102" height="84" alt="Imagen de muestra"/>';
}
```

The strange thing is that `/images/no_picture.jpg` is shown perfectly. Thanks again for any help you can give me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony problably doesn't support symlinks. Try doing [`mount --bind`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) instead, which should be transparent to the application.

---

Your updated question: You must have an extension for the `<img />` tag to work.

Comment: Or hardlink to the files... Possibly not the best idea but it would certainly work

Comment: @Dave: But that requires them to be on the same volume, right?

Comment: Yes... does it say anywhere in the Q that they aren't on the same volume? Genuine question - I'm pretty tired and may have missed it, even after re-reading it... and yes, I'm going to stop now cos tired answers are no use to anyone.

Comment: hey people! thanks for your efforts! please check my edited question. The files are indeed in the same volume, just different folders.

Comment: what do u mean with an extension? some mod of apache? well, i can display images with the `<img>` tag, but just images directly under the `/web/images` folder, any picture under a `/web/images` subfolder (lets say `/web/images/products`) isnt displayed. =/

Comment: @Throoze: No I mean that `<img src="/images/productos/'.$producto->id.'_muestra"` should be something like `<img src="/images/productos/'.$producto->id.'_muestra.jpg"`. Notice `.jpg`.

Comment: no, the thing is, since im sharing the resources with other project, i cant alter any file. Pictures in the folder im pointing with my symlink are stored without extension. i.e. `546_muestra` thats why i didnt use any symfony helper, since it adds `.png` by default when no extension is passed to the helper...

Comment: @Throoze: Well then that's your problem. As far I know browsers require you to provide an extension, so it can determine what type of image it is :(

Comment: well... I dont know if an extension is mandatory, but i solved it, in a very bad way, but it works hehehe. I created another `.htaccess` file inside my `/web/images` folder. In that file, just wrote: `Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine Off
</IfModule>` 

hehehe maybe not the best to do, but it works! =)